# How do I turn off TinyMCE's HTML validation?

Tags: validation, tinymce, code-cleanup

[This](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pecaab/6) is my configuration. I have

```
verify_html : false
```

there. But, for instance, the following code:

```
<ul>
    <h3>h3</h3>
    <li>el1</li>
    <li>el2</li>
</ul>
```

is converted to:

```
<h3>h3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>el1</li>
    <li>el2</li>
</ul>
```

It's **TinyMCE 3.5.6**. `cleanup` option is deprecated. So I have no idea how to turn it off.

I know it is weird that `h3` is there under `ul`. But some people have
a lot of side effects with such kind of cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to disable validation. But you can define how tinymce will treat html tags. Here is a setting which will keep the `h3` where you want it to be, but you need to configure that `h3`-tags may be children of `ul`-tags:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/mfcaab

Comment: You mean `valid_children`. Yes, I'm already using it. I guess it should be an option in my CMS. However, after upgrading from TinyMCE 3.2b to 3.5.6 some people have lots of invalid code... Then I'll allow some invalid combinations and expose them to the user. However, in official docs they don't mention how much xhtml validation is applied by default(the part which couldn't be switched off).

Comment: yes, valid_children is the way to go here. you will need to allow those combinations that tinymce verifies as error.